# project empty after pushing to gitlab in Xcode

Tags: gitlab, xcode10.1

hello guy's I have created a Xcode project but I am unable to put it on gitlab when I am committing project and clone it's empty

I am using these structure to push project

```
1.git clone http://192.168.10.245/snymob/ESN_IOS.git

2.git add ESN

3.git commit -m "msg"

4.git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

After cloning `ESN_IOS.git`, you need to `cd` into that folder `ESN_IOS/`, *before* doing any `git add`, `commit` and `push`.

Or: you are already in a repository, in which case:

- `ESN` folder is empty, and it won't be added by Git
- or `ESN` is itself a nested Git repository, and you will add and commit only a gitlink (a SHA1 reference)

Comment: I have done that in esn directory but it's null again

Comment: @HesamIlyaei is the ESN folder empty? Is it a git repo (with a .git subfolder inside)?

Comment: when I'm cloning the project in terminal shows the count is 4 but its empty